# React Native - Bottom Sheet always shows up on mount

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, bottom-sheet

I am using React Native with Expo and i am attempting to use Gorhom's Bottom Sheet component to display a bottom sheet when a user clicks on a button. Everything works fine except the bottom sheet insists to always pop up on screen mount, which is obviously bad, it should only pop up when user clicks on a trigger like a button.

Here's my component:

```
import BottomSheet, { BottomSheetScrollView } from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet'

<BottomSheet
      ref={sheetRef}
      enableOverDrag
      handleIndicatorStyle={styles.handleIndicator}
      snapPoints={snapPoints}
      enablePanDownToClose
    >
      <BottomSheetScrollView>
        {children}
      </BottomSheetScrollView>
    </BottomSheet>
```

I've tried to toggle a display none/flex but that makes the popup not smooth and very sudden:

```
containerStyle={[styles.container, {display: showSheet ? 'flex' : 'none'}]}
```

I've went through the entire docs twice but found nothing that can help me.

Comment: Can the `index` props help? https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/props/#index

Comment: wow yes, for some reason i didn't see that. thanks!

Comment: I was banging my head for two days as I missed the index too. Thanks @kiuQ and Atomics

Answer (score 3):

If the expected behavior is to only show the bottom sheet when the user clicks a button, then it's looking more like a modal. There's the `BottomSheetModal` wrapper/decorator for that.

Instead of importing `BottomSheet`, import `BottomSheetModal`. Then get its reference and call the methods `bottomSheetRef.current.present()` and `bottomSheetRef.current.close()`. Doing it this way, all the show/hide up/down animations will work right off the bet.

Take a look at the [documentation](https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/modal/usage) for a full example.

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with this issue for quite some time too. You can set the "index" to "-1" to initiate the bottom sheet in the closed state. here is the reference link.

https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/props/#index

Answer (score 1):

I use this logic

1. State variable

   const [showSearchFilter, setShowSearchFilter] = useState(false);
2. Method

   const toggleSearchFilter = (isDragDown?:boolean)=>{
   console.log("isDragDown:  ",isDragDown)
   setShowSearchFilter(!showSearchFilter);

   }
3. TSX code

   ```
   {
      showSearchFilter ? (
        <BottomSheet
        ref={bottomSheetRef}
        index={1}
        snapPoints={snapPoints}
        onChange={handleSheetChanges}
        style={$bottomSheetStyle}
        backgroundStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' }}
        handleStyle={$handleStyle}
        handleIndicatorStyle={$handleIndicatorStyle}
        enablePanDownToClose={true}
        onClose={toggleSearchFilter}
        footerComponent={() => (
          <View style={$footerContainerStyle}>
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
              <Button text="Reset" onPress={resetSearchFilters} style= 
                {$bigButtonStyle} textStyle={$bigButtonTextStyle} />
            </View>
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
              <Button text="Apply" onPress={applySearchFilters} style= 
       {[$bigButtonStyle, { backgroundColor: colors.palette.primary100 
           }]} textStyle={$bigButtonTextStyle} />
            </View>
          </View>
        )}
      >
        <BottomSheetScrollView style={[$contentContainer, 
           $bottomContainerInsets]}>
          <TextField
            ref={projectNameRef}
            onChangeText={text => projectNameRef.text = text}
            label="Project Name"
            style={{ minHeight: 20 }}
            onFocus={() => setFocusedInput("projectName")}
            onBlur={() => setFocusedInput("")}
            inputWrapperStyle={[
              $numberField,
              isProjectNameRefFocused && { borderColor: 
            colors.palette.primary100 }
            ]}
            containerStyle={{ marginTop: 10 }}
          />
          <TextField
            ref={productIDRef}
            onChangeText={text => productIDRef.text = text}
            label="Product ID"
            style={{ minHeight: 20 }}
            onFocus={() => setFocusedInput("productID")}
            onBlur={() => setFocusedInput("")}
            inputWrapperStyle={[
              $numberField,
              isProductIDFocused && { borderColor: 
             colors.palette.primary100 }
            ]}
            containerStyle={{ marginTop: 10 }}
          />
          <TextField
            ref={productTypeRef}
            onChangeText={text => productTypeRef.text = text}
            label="Product Type"
            style={{ minHeight: 20 }}
            onFocus={() => setFocusedInput("productType")}
            onBlur={() => setFocusedInput("")}
            inputWrapperStyle={[
              $numberField,
              isProductTypeRefFocused && { borderColor: 
        colors.palette.primary100 }
            ]}
            containerStyle={{ marginTop: 10 }}
          />

        </BottomSheetScrollView>
      </BottomSheet>
    ) : null
   }
   ```